# How can I force VS Code to be consistent for indentation?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have two `docker-compose.yml` files in two different projects.

For one, VS Code uses 2 spaces as the indentation space, for the other it uses 4 spaces.

This happens for almost all of file types. `.js` files and `.jsx` files and `.html` files.

We want to make it deterministics for all files regardless of their types and extensions.

We want to force VS Code to indent each new line by 4 spaces, or a simple tab.

Is that possible?

We looked at `Edior: Tab Size` and it already says 4. So, where does 2 spaces come from?

Comment: prob has something to do with user vs workspace settings, have you read these docs? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

Comment: @pzutils we do not use workspace settings at all. So for us this is not a factor. Thanks.